# How to assign form.action in jscript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script bound to a dropdown control.

```
function ddlDatabase_OnChange(e) {
    var form =this.form;
    form.action = 'Designer\\ddlDatabase_OnChange';
    form.submit();
}
```

the first time a selection is made the url is:

```
http://localhost:5321/Designer/ddlDatabase_OnChange
```

This is expected and the backend action is invoked.

However, on subsequent invocations, the result is:

```
http://localhost:5321/Designer/Designer/ddlDatabase_OnChange
```

Is there a method I am supposed to use when setting an action ?. I se the same behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the relative path that is assigned...

```
form.action = '/Designer/ddlDatabase_OnChange';
```

Comment: right...so what is the correct way to make the assignment ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
form.attr("action", '/Designer/ddlDatabase_OnChange');
```

Comment: would you mind writing the complete function. I can't get what you wrote to do anything.

Comment: I am getting: "Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'"

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working, although I thought I tried it earlier:

```
function ddlDatabase_OnChange(e) {
    var form = <HTMLFormElement>this.form;
    this.form.setAttribute("action", '/Designer/ddlDatabase_OnChange');
    form.submit();
}
```

And I think the leading '/' is important.